# C# How to make a list out of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I'm currently playing with TvDbSharper (https://github.com/HristoKolev/TvDbSharper) and i have a question about IEnumerable.
What i'm trying to do is get all the Id for a given series and then add the result in a listView.

This code gives me the first Id in the list:

```
const int SeriesId = 78804;
var tasks = new List<Task<TvDbResponse<BasicEpisode[]>>>();
var firstResponse = await client.Series.GetEpisodesAsync(SeriesId, 1);
for (int i = 2; i <= firstResponse.Links.Last; i++)
{
tasks.Add(client.Series.GetEpisodesAsync(SeriesId, i));
}
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var episodes = firstResponse.Data.Concat(results.SelectMany(x => x.Data));

epsListview.View = View.Details;
epsListview.Columns.Add("Episode", 100);
string[] arr = new string[4];
ListViewItem itm;
arr[0] = episodes.First().Id.ToString();
itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
epsListview.Items.Add(itm);
```

but what i want is to make a new line in the epsListview for each id available.

I never used IEnumerable and i'm still very novice using c#, i've been stuck with this problem for over a week now. can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but `.ToList()` will convert an `IEnumerable` into a `List`.

Comment: Do you know how to use a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're wanting to build an array of IDs from an IEnumerable of episodes, and add that array to a single ListViewItem. This should do that.

```
string[] arr = episodes.Select(episode => episode.Id.ToString()).ToArray()
ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
epsListview.Items.Add(itm);
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed! I just learned something new ! Thanks alot !!!! :)

Comment: You're welcome. [LINQ extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable) are very useful for working with IEnumerables.